# Flutter app localization does not work on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, localization

I use my own solution to localize my flutter app, and it works fine on Android. However, in iOS the app is always-english and does not change its language to the devices language. 
The System I use in my app is the following:

```
class MyLocalization {
  MyLocalization(this.locale);

  final Locale locale;

  static MyLocalization of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<MyLocalization>(context, MyLocalization);
  }
  String get homeButton => _translation(const {
    'en': 'english',
    'de': 'Deutsch',
  });

  String _translation(Map<String, String> translations) {
    return translations[locale.languageCode] ?? translations['en'] ?? "!!!MISSING TEXT!!!";
  }
}
```

iOS ignores this. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the link [Appendix: Updating the iOS app bundle](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)
and scroll all the way to the end where you will find some setting that you need to do